# ActionScript repeat action after

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to reload xml file in to variable every let's say 10 seconds. I've tried numerous tutorials on timers but each and every one of them, waits the timer time, and then it repeats the actions each milisecond or so.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
timer.start();

function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("10 seconds");
}
```

What I want to simply do, is watch this repeat each 10 seconds, but so far, it waits 10 secnds, then it puts "10 seconds" in trace like every milisencod ...

I've been struggeling with this ActionScript thing for such a long time and it seems to me, it must be pretty simple thing to do nope?

Thanks for your time, Mart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE` instead of `TimerEvent.TIMER` like so :

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000, 1); // Add a 1 to repeat count
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
timer.start();

function onTimerComplete(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("10 seconds");
    timer.reset(); // Reset the timer count back to 0
    timer.start(); // Start the timer again
}
```

The above code repeats every ten seconds, the below code triggers once after ten seconds and does **not** trigger again :

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000, 1); // Add a 1 to repeat count
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
timer.start();

function onTimerComplete(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("10 seconds");
}
```

Comment: This on the other hand, deosnt trace anything at all, am I missing something mate?

Comment: Hi there Johny, yes, it starts now fine :) but as soons as it starts, it just repeats itself in trace every milisecond. I feel like I have maybe something set up wrong? Im very new to this and cant seem to get grasp of it, not to mention its probably only this one thing I will ever do in flash / action script :))

Comment: Hey Martin, do you want it to repeat every ten seconds or do you just want it done once?

Comment: I'd love to load the function every 10 seconds yes :) but for some reasson, it waits 10 seconds, and then trace is filled with river of "10 seconds" faster than fast and furious :)

Comment: Oh that's weird, I ran the code on my copy of Flash and it executed a trace every ten seconds. One difference could be that my code is in a class and yours is on the timeline... hmm. Just out of curriosity does the frame that contains this code repeat over and over again?

Comment: Now you got me! It is in frame, but I have no idea about the repetition. So shall I put it in class then? :)) thats way more rollercoaster then this hehe :))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22349/discussion-between-martin-and-jonny-henly)

Answer (score 0):

You have a frame issue and I think you are not running the debugger version of player.
Try this.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000, 1); // Add a 1 to repeat count
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(evt:TimerEvent):void {trace("10 seconds");});
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have this code in your frame and it's creating a new timer & listener EVERY frame :

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
timer.start();
```